# Simple and easy Open Source CAD tools for basic 2D and 3D designs

Tags: cad, autocad, 3d-printing, computer-aided-design

We are planning to start a basic course on Computer Aided Designs (2D and 2D) for high school kids.

The idea  is to help them shape their innovative ideas into something tangible.   We shall finally help them develop prototype using 3D printers or mass produce later on.

We would like to know what all open source  options are available for 2d and 3d designs. Most importantly we are looking for tools which are simple and easy enough so that high school students  can use it (we will be limiting to simple designs).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use the available internet search engines to find opinionated answers to this type of question

Comment: There is a software recommendation SE site which is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: Autodesk software is also free for students and is an industry standard software, with many tutorials and support available.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't open source, but for students [Onshape](https://www.onshape.com) is free. Onshape runs in the browser so it will work on pretty much any current computer regardless of operating system. It is real 3D solid modeling with good 2D drafting. I've played with it some and it works remarkably well and as CAD programs go is easy to learn. Because it is cloud based, it greatly fosters collaboration which could be great for student teams. In addition, Onshape provides a lot of [learning resources](https://learn.onshape.com) including [videos](https://www.onshape.com/video) so teaching it should be enhanced.

[image: Onshape Screen Shot]